# php7 does not support bool in unserialize function?

Tags: php

I am trying to use the `unserialize` function with the second param that was introduced in php7 (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

However, it looks like php generates an error saying the second param should be an array and not a bool value https://3v4l.org/9PhpO
Does anyone have any idea why this behaviour?

Comment: Its a associative `Array` second parameter. You can try like this `unserialize($y, array(true))`.

Comment: Second parameter must be an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the source code of php https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/var.c#L1013-L1068

And found that the actual syntax is `unserialize($y, ['allowed_classes' => true])`

Run: https://3v4l.org/Bs2HR